# Why does my cactus have a bald spot? And any idea what type of cacti this is?

Tags: cactus

Cacti, unsure what type... balding in one spot but rest of hairs seem healthy, any idea why?

---

[image: cactus]

Comment: Might be *Parodia*, but I'am not sure. Flowers always help for good ID. Can you explain more what happened with the bald spot? I mean did the spines all of a sudden drop off, or was it bald during growth already? Any strange things happening during that time (cold, hot, etc.)?

Comment: They just fell off, nothing unusual happened it was growing fine with full spines... the weather was really hot then really cold, but it is kept inside

Comment: Does it get enough sunlight? Fertilizer? Seems cacti like these lose spines when they are not in perfect health. Can be anything that causes the unhealthy condition. Advice is to give your cactus perfect conditions, like right amount of light, water, fertilizer, etc.